# Can an input of type select be done with an option that does not go sweep a list?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

an option can be just an object instead of a list of objects?

in the documentation each sweeps a list but I would like to retrieve a single object

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
  <option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" 
          th:value="${type}" 
          th:text="#{${'seedstarter.type.' + type}}">Wireframe</option>
</select>
```

is possible do somethint like

```
  <option th:each="${Types}"
```

Comment: You don't need to use `th:each` in that case.  Just put `<option th:value="${type}" th:text="#{${'seedstarter.type.' + type}}">Wireframe</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Standard Dialect in thymeleaf offers Using `th:each`. Its the Iteration basics.

“for each element in the result of evaluating ${allTypes}, repeat this fragment of template setting that element into a variable called type”.

Dropdown Selector usually is for a list of options to be displayed.

You simply cant do `th:each="${Types}"`, as you need to declare a variable to access the iterated variable

https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#using-theach